# Unable to connect with GRIDDB using SQL workbench

Tags: griddb, sql-workbench-j

I need to connect to a GRIDDB instance running on a CentOS 7 machine by using SQL workbench from my Windows 10 machine.

I have setup the GRIDDB environment on CentOS 7 VM on Hyper-V. I am successful in taking a putty session of my VM, and can also ping the machine. But when I tried to connect with my GRIDDB database using SQL Workbench it takes ages in trying to establish a connection, and then the following error arises.

> [145028:JC_BAD_CONNECTION] Connection problem occurred (retryCount=100, elapsedMillis=302970, failureMillis=300963, queryTimeoutMillis=(not bounded), loginTimeoutMillis=300000, operation=LOGIN, reason=[145028:JC_BAD_CONNECTION] Connection unexpectedly terminated (address=/192.168.0.106:10040)) [SQL State=00, DB Errorcode=145028]